# Laravel form submit unsuccessful returns blank page instead of redirect home

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have a laravel form to create a new product entry in a database on submit, am supposed to be redirected back but I get a completely blank page without any errors. There is no new entry in my database when I check. The form is made up of various text fields, an image URL, and a multi-selected Image URL

please this is my blade template

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('products.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Create Product</h4><br><br>
                                @csrf

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="row mbr-1">
                                            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                                                    id="example-text-input">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end row -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <div class="row mb-3">
                                            <label for="example-text-input"
                                                class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                                                    id="example-text-input">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end row -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Price</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="catchy_title" class="form-control" type="number"
                                                value="" id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Status</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="status" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                                                id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product
                                    Description</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <textarea id="elm1" name="long_description" placeholder="Please enter a vivid description of the product"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end row -->
                        </div>


                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tags</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="tags" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                                                id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">

                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Estimated
                                            Delivery
                                            Time</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="estimated_delivery_time" class="form-control" type="text"
                                                value="" id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Available
                                            Quantity</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="available_quantity" class="form-control" type="text"
                                                value="" id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Colors</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="colors" class="form-control" type="text" value=""
                                                id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Supplier's
                                            Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="supplier_name" class="form-control" type="text"
                                                value="" id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Supplier's
                                            Contact</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="supplier_contact" class="form-control" type="text"
                                                value="" id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Video Url /
                                            Link</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="video_description" class="form-control" type="text"
                                                value="" id="example-text-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Primarry
                                            Image</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="primary_image" accept="image/*" class="form-control"
                                                type="file" id="image">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Primary Image
                                            Preview</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <img id="showImage" class="" width="300px"
                                                src="{{ !empty($Product->image) ? url('upload/products/' . $product->image) : url('upload/no_image.jpg') }}"
                                                alt="Hero image">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Add Other
                                            Images</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input name="multi_image[]" accept="image/*" class="form-control"
                                                type="file" id="image" multiple="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end row -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light"
                                value="Create Product">
                            </form>
```

and this is my store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->file('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $name_gen = hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();  // 3434343443.jpg

        Image::make($image)->resize(523,605)->save('upload/home_about/'.$name_gen);
        $save_url = 'upload/products/'.$name_gen;

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'status' => $request -> status,
            'tags' => $request -> tags,
            'estimated_delivery_time' => $request->estimated_delivery_time,
            'available_quantity' => $request->available_quantity,
            'colors' => $request->colors,
            'supplier_name' => $request->supplier_name,
            'supplier_phone' => $request->supplier_phone,
            'video_description' => $request->video_description,
            'primary_image' => $save_url,
            'other_images' => $save_url,

        ]);
        $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Product created successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

thank you for taking some time to review

Comment: What do you get when you `dd($request)` at the top of your store method?

Comment: Your if condition checking for an image is failing.

Comment: enter `dd($request->all())` at the top of the code inside the store function. and verify your request is reaching to the store function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are validating the request but not saving it to database.
after the validation and before the return you should do like this to save in database.

```
            $item=new YOUR_MODEL_NAME:
            $item->name => $request->name,
            $item->category => $request->category,
            $item->price => $request->price,
            $item->description => $request->description,
            $item->status => $request -> status,
            $item->tags => $request -> tags,
            $item->estimated_delivery_time => $request->estimated_delivery_time,
            $item->available_quantity => $request->available_quantity,
            $item->colors => $request->colors,
            $item->supplier_name => $request->supplier_name,
            $item->supplier_phone => $request->supplier_phone,
            $item->video_description => $request->video_description,
            $item->primary_image => $save_url,
            $item->other_images => $save_url,
            $item->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'status' => $request -> status,
            'tags' => $request -> tags,
            'estimated_delivery_time' => $request->estimated_delivery_time,
            'available_quantity' => $request->available_quantity,
            'colors' => $request->colors,
            'supplier_name' => $request->supplier_name,
            'supplier_phone' => $request->supplier_phone,
            'video_description' => $request->video_description,
            'primary_image' => $save_url,
            'other_images' => $save_url,

        ]);
```

In the snippet above you're performing the validation, but I don't see a request to persist the data to your database in your `store()` function.

It's recommended to utilize the functionality provided by the framework when checking for request input presence. These functions usually provide quality-of-life aspects such as checking for multiple input presence and conditional callbacks as well.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present

```
if ($request->has('name')) {
    //
}
```

You should also be calling the `validate()` method on `$request`, not `$this`.

First, I'd like to recommend that you utilize a Form Request
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation

Second, use the validated data and mass assignment when storing the new model. If the validated data structure is not 1:1 with the table schema, you could always assign the values manually but this will result in a bloated controller. One possible solution is to utilize a DTO (Data Transfer Object) and provide the `validated()` array to the DTO when using mass assignment.

```
// Without DTO
Model::create($modelStoreRequest->validated());

// With DTO
$DTO = new MyDTO($modelStore$request->validated())->toArray();
Model::create($DTO);
```

**Note that if the incoming request fields do not pass the given validation rules Laravel will automatically redirect the user back to their previous location. In addition, all of the validation errors and request input will automatically be flashed to the session.**

Answer (score -1):

Try to be specific, pass route where you want to redirect like below:

```
return redirect()->route('route-name-here')->with($notification);
```

Comment: Why? What if there are more then one route that post to this method?